# Running a gif by a thread call on Python (PyQt)

Tags: multithreading, animation, pyqt, label, gif

I am using an animation class to show a spritesheet as a gif on a label (code here: http://python.su/forum/topic/15679/?page=1#post-94136). To do that on a PyQt application, I'm running on a different thread, by using signal to comunicate, once I don't want to stop the main thread.

But when I click on the label_2, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Alexandre\Desktop\breakingthread\animation.py", line 21, in _animation_step
    self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[self._current_frame])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea how to solve?

Full code below:

mainwindow.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'bt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(473, 700)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(473, 700))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 473, 700)
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/bg.png")))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 610, 286, 42))
        self.label_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.label_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("images/click.png")))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Breaking Thread", None))
```

runner.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL
from animation import SpriteAnimation
import sys
import mainwindow

class animateLabel(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def animate_label(self):
        print "inicio thread"

    def run(self):
        self.animate_label()
        self.emit(SIGNAL('init_animate()'))

class App(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label_2.mousePressEvent = self.call_animation

    def call_animation(self, event):
        self.get_thread = animateLabel()
        self.connect(self.get_thread, SIGNAL("finished()"), self.done)
        self.connect(self.get_thread, SIGNAL("init_animate()"), self.init_animate)
        self.get_thread.start()

    def init_animate(self):
        self.animation = SpriteAnimation('image/click', 286, 42, self.label_2)
        self.animation.play()

    def done(self):
        print "fim thread"

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = App()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like `SpriteAnimation._animation_step` can fail if `self.pixmaps` is empty, can you check if that's the case?

Comment: Actually that was the problem! Thank you very much! I was passing the wrong path here: self.animation = SpriteAnimation('image/click', 286, 42, self.label_2). It is missing an "s" on the end of "image" hahah